# sql group by with excluded data

Tags: mysql, sql

My table:

```
id  | request |  subject     | date
1   |    5    |      1       |  576677
2   |    2    |      3       |  576698 
3   |    5    |      1       |  576999 
4   |    2    |      3       |  586999
5   |    2    |      7       |  596999
```

Need to select unique records by two columns(request,subject). But if we have different pairs of request-subject(2-3, 2-7), this records should be excluded from resulted query.

My query now is:

```
SELECT MAX(id), id, request, subject, date
FROM `tbl`
GROUP BY request, subject
having count(request) > 1
order by MAX(id) desc
```

How to exclude record with id=4, id=5 from this query? Thanks!

Comment: please show the output required as a table

Comment: you question is not clear ..  update you question with the expected  result

Comment: Add `WHERE ID NOT IN ('4', '5')` above `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: selecting MAX(id) and id is an invalid combination. You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: expected result:  3   |    5    |      1       |  576999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may group by request, and then check for every group if all subjects in it are equal. You could do it using MIN() and MAX():

```
SELECT request, MIN(subject) AS subject
  FROM table_1
 GROUP BY request
HAVING MIN(subject) = MAX(subject)
```

As for your update, I assume you want all the fields for the max ID in the group (in your example, ID 3). The query would then look like this one:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_1 t
 WHERE t.id IN (SELECT MAX(s.id)
                  FROM table_1 s
                 GROUP BY s.request
                HAVING MIN(s.subject) = MAX(s.subject))
 ORDER BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
select * from MyTable T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM MyTable T2 
                 WHERE T1.id <> T2.id 
                       and T1.request = T2.request 
                       and T1.subject <> T2.subject)
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03a8ad/7/0)

Comment: we need to exclude records with id=2, id=5 because "if we have different pairs of request-subject(2-3, 2-7), this records should be excluded"

Comment: but (2, 7) is unique? i think we should remove one of (2,3) and (5,1)

Comment: if we have already doubled 2-3, or( 2-xxx) or any doubled request, then all with this request id 2,4,5 need to be excluded